# Ruby: force dns resolution through custom dns server

Tags: ruby, dns

I want to resolve the DNS requests issued from within a Ruby script through a DNS server, different from the ones in resolv.conf. While I could do that manualy by using Resolv::DNS or something like that, I'd like to do that for all the requests (like the ones issued by RestClient, for example). Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I modify DNS settings for a Ruby on Rails app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898330/can-i-modify-dns-settings-for-a-ruby-on-rails-app)

Answer (score -1):

RestClient uses `net/http` and uses the host name part of the provided URL to open a TCP socket:

https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/net/http.rb?source=cc#L879

The simplest way to change which host is accessed is to manually change the URL to use an IP address by performing the lookup yourself.

Alternatively, you can replace the resolver of the various `*Socket` classes, and there is actually an example of how to do this here: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/4c2304f0004e9f1784540f3d36976aad9eab1f68/lib/resolv-replace.rb